# How to write a query in yii2 for with rollup

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

how to write a find() with rollup :

```
 $leadsCount = Approval::find()
                ->select(['COUNT(id) AS cnt, coalesce(status, "total")'])
                ->groupBy(['status'])
                ->with(rollup)
                ->all();
```

While running the query am
getting an error like this : Use of undefined constant rollup - assumed 'rollup'

Comment: You have just posted a call of `find()` with `rollup`. What is your question then? Are you encountering an error when runnig the code? If you do, what is the error message?

Comment: getting an error like this : Use of undefined constant rollup - assumed 'rollup'

Comment: Well, add it to the question then.

Comment: PHP don't have constant with name `rollup` - as youre trying here to use, and method `with()` is for adding relations, not grouping by with rollup.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean this:

```
 $leadsCount = Approval::find()
                ->select(['COUNT(id) AS cnt, coalesce(`status`, "total")'])
                ->groupBy(new \yii\db\Expression('`status` ASC WITH ROLLUP'))
                ->all();
```

The method [`with()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait.html#with()-detail) is about object relations what is something completly different.

You also need to quote the column *status* since it is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-S) in MySQL.

btw: you may want to use [`asArray()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait.html#asArray()-detail) as well (`->asArray()->all();`) since you don't get Approval objects with this query.

Comment: getting the same error its not working, want to use ROLLUP with this query  to get the total of counts.

Comment: @AvinashRaut Updated my answer. Use backticks to quote the column. HTH

Comment: Class 'Yii\db\Expression' not found getting the same error @robsch

Comment: @AvinashRaut Not sure. Does it help if you prepend a backslash: `\yii\db\Expression`? I don't know why the class isn't found. Do you have some special setup? Doesn't your IDE support you with it? ... This is not the same error, it is a different one.

Comment: Am using netbeans its is suggesting me the same expression path but not sure why this is coming because of the library issue or something else.

Comment: Thanks robsch! Its working...

Comment: @AvinashRaut Fine! And what have been your last problem? Just curious.